Ubuntu 24.04 144Hz refresh rate
My biggest problem is that I have a second monitor (Gigabyte G34WQC) and although I have it set everywhere to run at 144Hz, it runs at 60Hz (ufotest proves it, for example). I have installed drivers version 535.183.01, which according to the Nvidia website is compatible with my graphics card (RTX 3060 notebook). Software & Updates shows me that the recommended drivers are nvidia-driver-550. On the other hand, the Nvidia website does not mention my graphics card for driver version 550. Unless it is not the fault of the drivers?
Results of nvidia-smi:

Results of xrandr:

Results of ufotest:


I have this bug with wayland too. You can switch to x11
